# Error shows: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1

Tags: android

Error shows: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1

```
public class NewProductActivity extends Activity {
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    EditText inputName;
    EditText inputPrice;
    EditText inputDesc;
    private static String url_create_product = "http://127.0.0.1/android_connect/create_product.php";
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    static List<String> citations = null;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add_product);
        inputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputName);
        inputPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputPrice);
        inputDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputDesc);
        Button btnCreateProduct = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCreateProduct);     
        btnCreateProduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // creating new product in background thread
                new CreateNewProduct().execute();
            }
        });
    }

    class CreateNewProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(NewProductActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Creating Product..");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            String name = inputName.getText().toString();
            String price = inputPrice.getText().toString();
            String description = inputDesc.getText().toString();
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("price", price));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("description", description));
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,
                    "POST", params);
            Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AllProductsActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                } else {
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `CreateNewProduct` class need lots of improvement in order to implement `AsyncTask` correctly  and what about if user press `btnCreateProduct` more then one time?

Comment: please post [logcat](https://politecuriosity.files.wordpress.com/2013/05/logcat.jpg).

Answer (score 1):

Move in your `onPostExecute(....)`

```
 Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AllProductsActivity.class);
 startActivity(i);
 finish();
```

Never  call `finish();` or `Intent`  in `doInBackground(....)`